# Checkbox shows div when ticked / unticked. But div is hidden when 'back' in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written this script that shows a div when a checkbox is ticked:

```
<cfinput type="Checkbox" name="Agency" value="Agency" id="Agency">Agency Team<br>

<div id="agcyTeam" style="display:none">
    <p>Blah Blah Blah
</div>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#Agency").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#agcyTeam").show();
        } else {
            $("#agcyTeam").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

This works, however when I submit, and then press back in the browser the checkbox is still checked, but the div is hidden. How do I make the div appear in this instance?

Comment: use change instead of click

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, you should use the `change` event on checkbox and radio inputs for accessibility reasons. Secondly you can shorten your code in the event handler to a single line using `toggle()`.

To solve your issue, raise a `change()` event on load to invoke the handler logic there:

```
$("#Agency").change(function () {
  $("#agcyTeam").toggle(this.checked);
}).trigger('change');
```